# Recursively find directory file counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a flat list of a few million files and I want to find the number of files per directory, recursively. An example of input/output for this would be:

```
# files.csv
/mnt/main/files/four.txt
/mnt/main/files/five.txt
/mnt/second/new.mov
```

And the output I want to get is:

```
{
    'mnt': 3,
    'mnt/main': 2,
    'mnt/main/files': 2,
    'mnt/second': 1
}
```

Currently I am doing something pretty naive such as:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
DIRS = defaultdict(int)
for file in files:
    for num in range(1, file.count('/')): # ignore escapes
        dir = '/' + '/'.join(file.split('/')[1:num+1])
        DIRS[dir] += 1

# {'/mnt/main/files': 2, '/mnt': 3, '/mnt/main': 2, '/mnt/second': 1}
```

What might be a better way to do this? I'm thinking potentially something that would use `yield`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can try this approach:

```py
import pathlib
from typing import List
from collections import Counter
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


#@dataclass
#class CountFiles:
#    files: List[str]
#    counter: Counter = field(default_factory=Counter)
#
#    def __post_init__(self):
class CountFiles:
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = files
        self.counter = Counter()
        for f in self.files:
            path = pathlib.Path(f)
            self.drill(path)

    def drill(self, path: pathlib.Path):
        self.counter[str(path.parent)] += 1
        if len(path.parts) > 1:
            return self.drill(path.parent)

    def show(self):
        return dict(self.counter.most_common())


files = [
    '/mnt/main/files/four.txt',
    '/mnt/main/files/five.txt',
    '/mnt/second/new.mov'
]

cf = CountFiles(files)
print(cf.show())
# {'/': 6, '/mnt': 3, '/mnt/main/files': 2, '/mnt/main': 2, '/mnt/second': 1}
```

Comment: thanks for this -- `dataclasses` are so great. (I think in the version of python I was using for the question it wasn't an option though).

Comment: dataclasses are only used in the example to simplify the logic. you should be able to achieve same behaviour using classing classes.

Comment: I just changed the post to use classic python classes, it should work exactly the same. just ignore the `dataclasses` and `typing` imports.